How do I record an audio in .wav file format that would meet the standard of Google Speech To Text API in React Native Expo?
I have a function that starts and stops recordings; when the recording stops, I can playback the recording, and everything works well, but whenever I upload the audio file to Google for transcription, I get an empty response. But when I upload another .wav file (downloaded online, not the recording), I got the transcription of that audio.
const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Requesting permissions..");
      const { status } = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need audio recording permissions to make this work!");
        return;
      }

      console.log("Starting recording..");
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync({
        android: {
          extension: ".wav",
          outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_DEFAULT,
          audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_DEFAULT,
          sampleRate: 16000,
          numberOfChannels: 1,
          bitRate: 128000,
        },
        ios: {
          extension: ".wav",
          audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_HIGH,
          sampleRate: 16000,
          numberOfChannels: 1,
          bitRate: 128000,
          linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
          linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
          linearPCMIsFloat: false,
        },
      });
      setRecording(recording);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    console.log("Stopping recording..");
    if (recording) {
      await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      const uri = recording.getURI();
      setRecording(null);
      uploadAudio(uri);
    }
  };

  function getOtherUser(data, username) {
    if (data.receiver.username !== username) {
      return data.receiver;
    }
    if (data.sender.username !== username) {
      return data.sender;
    }
    return null;
  }

  const uploadAudio = async (uri) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", {
      uri,
      name: "recording.wav",
      type: "audio/wav",
    });
    formData.append("pair_id", details.id);
    formData.append(
      "delivered",
      Object.values(members).some(
        (entry) => entry.name === receipient?.username,
      )
        ? true
        : false,
    );

    try {
      const url = `${API_URL}/api/record_view/`;
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          user: username,
        },
        body: formData,
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("File successfully uploaded");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading audio file:", error);
    }
  };

The above is my React Native Code
import os
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from google.cloud import speech_v2
from google.cloud.speech_v2.types import cloud_speech
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def transcribe_model_selection_v2(project_id: str, model: str, audio_path: str) -> cloud_speech.RecognizeResponse:
    """Transcribe an audio file."""
    # Instantiates a client with credentials
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('service-account-file.json')
    client = speech_v2.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)

    with open(audio_path, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()

    config = cloud_speech.RecognitionConfig(
        auto_decoding_config=cloud_speech.AutoDetectDecodingConfig(),
        language_codes=["en-US"],
        model=model,
    )

    request = cloud_speech.RecognizeRequest(
        recognizer=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/global/recognizers/_",
        config=config,
        content=content,
    )

    response = client.recognize(request=request)

    return response

@csrf_exempt
def transcribe_audio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('audio'):
        audio_file = request.FILES['audio']
        audio_path = f'/tmp/{audio_file.name}'
        
        with open(audio_path, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in audio_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)

        try:
            project_id = 'project-id'
            model = 'latest_long' 
            response = transcribe_model_selection_v2(project_id, model, audio_path)

            os.remove(audio_path)

            transcription = ''
            for result in response.results:
                transcription += result.alternatives[0].transcript

            return JsonResponse({'transcription': transcription})

        except Exception as e:
            os.remove(audio_path)
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)

    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)


The above is my django backend View for transcribing the uploaded audio

maybe use some tool to get parameters from working file and from your fie. e.g ffprobe in ffmpeg

don't you get response as JSON with some information?
